# Indefinite integral with trig components

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

The following integral has me stumped. Any help on how to go about solving it would be great.

$\int\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin2\theta - 1}d\theta$

Comment: wolfram shows to be quite an ugly integral. Where did you get this, out of curiosity?

Comment: It showed up on a Calc 2 test the other day, not surprisingly I had gotten it wrong. I am just making sure that I am able to do it.

Comment: For a Calc 2 test, this is quite a challenge.

Comment: If you would like to see the integral: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+cos%28x%29%2F%28sin%282x%29-1%29)

Comment: After a bit of mucking about, I'm certain that a closed form solution can be found with a Weierstrass (tangent half-angle) substitution. That reduces it to a rational expression which can (theoretically) be put through polynomial long division then decomposed into partial fractions. But the denominator is a quartic without a rational root. It'll be ugly, really ugly, especially when you consider that the expression you get at the end is in terms of the tangent of half the initial variable.

Comment: BTW, to the original asker: are you absolutely positive this wasn't set as a definite integral? If the bounds are "nice" and one is "clever" enough, those can often be solved without actually finding the indefinite integral.

Comment: I went down that rabbit hole myself, I quit when I realized that  it would not factor into something that is easy to play with. And, it is indefinite.

Comment: @VarunIyer: It doesn't look so ugly to me: $$\dfrac1{2(\sin x-\cos x)}-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\tanh^{-1}\bigg[\dfrac{1+\tan\frac x2}{\sqrt2}\bigg]$$

Comment: @Lucian Maybe not to you, but this is a calculus 2 course. Normally you wouldn't be dealing with this difficult of an integral, although there are some to pop up occasionally. In my calculus 2 course, I can safely say that we didn't cover integrals as difficult as this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}-x$, the integral becomes
$$
\int \frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}-x)}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-2x)-1}\,(-dx)
= -\int \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cos x + \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sin x}{\cos 2x -1}\,dx
= \frac{-1}{\sqrt2} \int\frac{\cos x+\sin x}{(1-2\sin^2 x)-1} \, dx
= \frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\left( \int \frac{\cos x \, dx}{\sin^2 x} + \int\frac{\sin x \, dx}{1-\cos^2 x} \right) = \ldots
$$
Maybe you can take it from there?

Comment: This looks like it takes care of it. Thanks!

Comment: why can you set $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}-x$?

Comment: @user71207: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution